# ¿Se puede publicar mas de una pagina en git hub pages, con perfil personal?

Tags: github, github-pages

Me gustaria saber como publicar mas de una pagina, ya que se que se puede al crear el respositorio nombrandolo con tu nombre de usuario.github.io pero ese nombre solo puede usarse una vez

Comment: Github: "Solo puedes crear un sitio de organización o de usuario para cada cuenta en GitHub. Los sitios de proyectos, ya sean propiedad de una cuenta de organización o personal, son ilimitados." Pero eso no significa que no puedas crear un sitio de sitios en Github

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.